# .htaccess 301 redirect remove [] from the URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, rewrite, apache2, 301-redirect

I want to remove '[' and ']' from the URLs and redirect to correct link.

Here is a sample URL:

```
/forums/garage-150/cool-cars-sightings-[archived]-7610/index127.html
```

Needs to be redirected to:

```
/forums/garage-150/cool-cars-sightings-archived-7610/index127.html
```

Here is what I have composed so far, but still not working..

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/forums/(.*)/(.+)\[(.+)\](.+)/(.+)$ /forums/$1/$2$3$4/$5 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directive looks OK, except if this is in `.htaccess` then you'll need to remove the slash prefix from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^forums/(.+)/(.+)\[(.+)\](.+)/(.+)$ /forums/$1/$2$3$4/$5 [R=301,L]
```

`RewriteRule` directives in a *directory* context (which includes `.htaccess`) match against the URL-path *less the directory-prefix*. The *directory-prefix* always ends with a slash, so the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against never starts with a slash.

You may need to add the `L` flag if you (plan to) have more directives. (I also changed the first captured group from `.*` to `.+`, since a zero-width match here is impossible.

---

**UPDATE:**

> The htaccess where I put this code is in `/` directory. **There is also `.htaccess` in `/forums` directory**

If there is an existing `.htaccess` file in the `/forums` subdirectory that also uses mod_rewrite, then (by default) this will completely override the directive above (in your root `.htaccess` file). The above directive will not even be processed.

The easiest way to resolve this is to move the above directive into the `/forums/.htaccess` file (near the top). Since this redirect is specific to the forum, that would also seem to be the most logical approach. However, you would also need to change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to read:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)\[(.+)\](.+)/(.+)$ /forums/$1/$2$3$4/$5 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: it didn't work. it does not redirect..

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? If so, where have you placed this directive? (It would need to go near the top, before any other rewrites.) Do you have any other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path?

Comment: The htaccess where I put this code is in / directory.
There is also .htaccess in /forums directory

Comment: If there is an additional `.htaccess` file in the `/forums` subdirectory that this is most likely overriding your redirect. I've updated my answer.